# Facebook like button statistics

Tags: php, html, facebook, social-networking

I have a website with a lot of pages that have like buttons on them.
I would like to know which pages receive how many likes.

In Facebook Insight I see only my fan page statistic.

I searched with no success, is there any solution?

EDIT:

**there was a comment regarding to Insight for domains, now I can't find it. This is exactly what I need, I thinked it is only for fan pages.
Unfortunatelly Popular Pages shows only today's data: http://d.pr/aBbD+ ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook, who liked our fan page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818286/facebook-who-liked-our-fan-page)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a URL to the Facebook Graph API to get the number of Facebook shares (includes likes and times the URL was posted to peoples' walls).

For example, here's StackOverflow:
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F

Comment: What about https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F6847931%2Ffacebook-like-button-statistics%2F6847979#6847979 ?

Comment: Something like that would be OK, but in an user friendly format, because I have 500link on my site. http://www.sundh.com/blog/2010/11/get-likes-on-urls-from-facebook/ this doesn't work for me.

Comment: as I seid in my answer, it depends on user which shared that... if he has restricted access to this kind of things, he won't be counted in

Comment: @Adrian Sure, you'd need to fetch this server-side if you wanted to display it nicely to users. You didn't say it needed to be user-friendly on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that this only works with the XFBML version of the Facebook Like button. If you’re currently using the iframe version, you can generate a new version of the code by visiting the Facebook Developer page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _paq = _paq || [];
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    // Put your custom event-tracking script here
    _paq.push(["trackConversion", {
      id: "YOUR_EVENT_ID"
    }]);
  });
</script>
```

If you want to track “dislikes” too, simply duplicate that block of code and change “edge.create” to “edge.remove” instead. And that’s it

Comment: That won't do anything if they like/dislike within Facebook instead of on your page.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible, in case user don't want to show it to you

https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F6847931%2Ffacebook-like-button-statistics%2F6847979

I shared it, but I restricted access to my profile to everyone, so you will not see my share.

About likes, it'S same

Look at their [privacy policy](http://www.facebook.com/privacy/explanation.php)