# How to get users who liked my website pages?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am generating Like buttons for each of all my pages, objects or something that can be liked. After that I want to display on a page called "User statistics" all users who liked pages. 
Searched web - nothing interesting.

Need a server side solution, no JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook, who liked our fan page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818286/facebook-who-liked-our-fan-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There's isn't a summary page. 
But you can see number of shares/likes by using Graph API, for example

http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: 1+, just a note that this might be possible if the users are connected to his site through Facebook.

Comment: @ifa connected, like ... what? So shares/likes do not show when they're not logged in via FB?

Comment: No. let me explain: if you use Facebook connect in your site then you have two type: 1) connected user (who you know his FB ID) 2) non-connected user. Now obviously both types can still use the Like plugin (unless you restrict it by hiding it for non-connected), so if ONLY members (connected users) can use the Like plugin then he can capture that through the `egde.create` event and store it along with the user id.